# Eclipse - Run starts new emulator each time

Tags: android, android-emulator

I Have problem while i run the application in eclipse and Each time it starts new emulator.

Please anyone help to run application with existing emulator or opened emulator in eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go into **Run** > **Run Configurations**
2. Choose you app from the left under **Android Applications**
3. Choose the **Target** tab on the right
4. Choose **Automatically pick compatible device...**
5. Choose your AVD device.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Run->Run Configuration-> target->select always pick the device->apply`